# joining domain - store password and avoid prompting password

Tags: linux, windows, samba, active-directory

While joining a domain from a linux machine , I give this command:
net rpc join member -U Administrator.
Now, the above command prompts for (Administrator) password.

Now, I wish to store the password somewhere(smb.conf OR krb5.conf) so that it does not prompts for password. Is it possible?

Note:Necessary changes to join a domain are carried out in /etc/samba/smb.conf

PS: Please do not consider any security issue with this.

Thanks!

Comment: ACtually the command accepts password as parameter it should be given like: net rpc join member -U Administrator%password...Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

You should only need to join the domain once per machine, once your machine has been joined the machine account secret will be stored in a database file on your system.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if what you are asking for is possible, but if that `net rpc join` command doesn't accept the password as a parameter, and doesn't accept it via pipe redirection either, you can try wrapping it up in an `expect` script.